# Discretization Using ZOH, FOH and Tustis bilinear Transformation

Tags: control, control-system, zoh

I am very new to this forum, so excuse me if i do not write the equations properly. And I'm pretty new to DSP too, so this might be very basics for most of you, but it's pretty complicated to me.

I need to discretize a PT1 filter:

\$T\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + y(t) = u(t)\$

I need to discrtize this using ZOH, FOH and Tustins bilinear transformation. 
I need to apply this filter to my signal, using a for loop( yes i have Fc, Wn).
I know this can be easily done in Matlab. but i wanna understand how it's done by hand.I could not understand anything from google.

Any leads would help me.

Edit1 @JonRB: Matlab Script:

```
% define a continuous-time first order low-pass filter in state-space
% notation. differential equation of the filter:
%  T * y'(t) + y(t) = u(t)
% -> State-space notation:
%  x'(t) = -1/T * x + 1/T * u
  % -3dB cutoff frequency: 100 Hz => omega_c = 2 * pi * 100 rad/s
% => T = 1 / omega_c
f_c = 10;
T = 1 / 2 / pi / f_c;
filt_cont = ss(-1/T, 1/T, 1, 0);
enter code here
% sampling period
Ts= 
% discretization of the filter 
filt_discr_zoh = c2d(filt_cont, Ts, 'zoh');
filt_discr_foh = c2d(filt_cont, Ts, 'foh');
filt_discr_tustin = c2d(filt_cont, Ts, 'tustin');
```

Comment: What is 1^(t) ?

Comment: y dot of t. more like y′(t) @EugeneSh.

Comment: y dot of t or do you mean -1 (ie delay). OR do you really mean 1st derivative?

Comment: 1st derivative. sorry for confusion

Comment: right, now it makes sense.

Comment: @JonRB, any luck?

Comment: So what have you exactly done to generate the difference equations for the three methods. This is appearing like homework now

Comment: @JonRB, Not an home work. I'm an intern. There was a task of applying filter to a signal with these 3 methods. In matlab it was easy as google helped me. But I want to understand how it works, so i thought i will make these 3 equations and apply it to the filter using a "for" loop. I'm trying hard to udnerstand, but no luck.

Comment: @JonRB need some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps that are required to realise a digital filter

Considering [Bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform)

This will facilitate taking a continuous time domain equation & converting it into an appropriate discrete time domain equation.

Copying into EE.SE just for completness

\$ H(s) = \frac{1}{1+ RCs} \$

an s-domain to z-domain transformation can be realised by substituting the s terms for the equivalent z-domain

\$ s \leftarrow \frac{2}{\Delta_T}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}\$

\$H(z) = \frac{1+z^{-1}}{(1+ \frac{2RC}{\Delta_T}) + (1- \frac{2RC}{\Delta_T})z^{-1}}  \$

With the discrete time domain equation, the difference equation can be realised via refactoring to find the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)

\$y_n = y_{n-1} + \alpha (x_n - y_{n-1})\$

where \$\alpha = \frac{\Delta_T}{\Delta_T + \tau}\$
and \$\tau = RC\$ the time constant.

\$y_n \$ represents present output

\$y_{n-1} \$ represents last output

\$x_n\$ represents present input

---

If you now look at the equation (slightly re-ordered) in the question

\$u(t)=  y(t) + T\frac{dy(t)}{dt}  \$

w.r.t. the difference equation:

\$y_n = y_{n-1} + \alpha (x_n - y_{n-1})\$

It can be seen that there is a correlation. The \$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\$ is represented by NEW - OLD and a scaling factor which has units of \$s^{-1}\$ : dy/dt

---

### Realization in Matlab:Simulink

Looking at the difference equation: \$ y_n = y_{n-1} + \alpha (x_n - y_{n-1}) \$

there is a need for

1. addition
2. multiplication
3. difference
4. gain

This is using a 10kHz sin generator, sample time of 1us and an \$\alpha\$ of 0.059117397, which is a \$\tau\$ of 1.59155e-5, the equivalent of 10 kHz

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation! Matlab simulation wasn't required. Any chance you can demonstrate solving with ZOH or FOH, no need of Simulink though.

Comment: this include ZoH, that is what the unit delay is & what Z^(-1) represents

Comment: Ah in Matlab, but i want the derivation by hand. I want a final equation for ZOH filter using state space maybe?.

Comment: but that is what the difference equation shows. the y(n-1) is the output of a ZoH block

Comment: Ok clearly i am lacking some basics here. Did u implement all 3 in the same equation? if So, could you give me 3 different equation?

Comment: I will add my matlab script, which i wanna do it in hand.

Comment: I have added a eddit, if you could see my script. "filt_discr_zoh" "filt_discr_foh" "filt_discr_tustin". 3 different methods. I want 3 different equation for each of the methods. I hope I have explained it properly